# Loop through 2d array, if value is true, append in an empty array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to loop through the second column of an array and pick out every value that == 1, then store the corresponding value from the first column in a new array.

```
array1 = []
array2 = ([10,0], [11,0], [12,1], [13,1], [14,0])
```

What I'm trying to do is,

```
for i in array2:
    if array2[:,1] == 1:
        array1[:,1] = array2[:,1]
```

But this gives me an error

> *ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()*

So, in theory, I should get something like:

```
array1 = [12, 13]
```

I managed to get the matching index values with the following, but can't figure it out for the columns.

```
array1 = np.array([i for i, row in enumerate(array2[:,1]) if row ==1])
```

Comment: I think the issue is `if array2[:,1] == 1`. Try printing `array2[:,1]` and you should find that it's an array, not a scalar. I THINK what you meant to do is `if array2[i,1] == 1` where you use the `i`

Answer (score 2):

First, your question is extremely misleading because nowhere do you mention NumPy, but that is what you are using based on the error messages you have.

So let's start with sample input of the type you're actually using, which is a NumPy array:

```
array2 = np.array([[10,0], [11,0], [12,1], [13,1], [14,0]])
```

Then, the solution is:

```
array2[array2[:,1] == 1, 0]
```

This gives:

```
array([12, 13])
```

You should always try to avoid `for` loops when working with NumPy arrays.   Looping over data is slow, doing it in vector form is fast.